# Use of unsigned on the heap

Tags: c, arrays, performance, unsigned-integer

I'm trying to find all instances in a C program that I've written in which I can improve performance. In a few places the program operates very slowly on account of large arrays allocated to the heap, where some of these arrays are integer arrays. I've read, here on stackoverflow and through other sources, that we should always make use of "unsigned" if there is no instance of a negative integer.

While I don't have many instances of division by factors of two, where performance could see a significant boost by making this change, is there a difference in the handling of memory for a large array of int vs. unsigned int? Similarly, does initializing a large array of ints with calloc operate differently when initializing the same array with unsigned int?

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you benchmark it ?

Comment: Look at the signature for `calloc` - it has no clue what type you're allocating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ISO C (C99), `int` is signed and has a minimum range of at least -32767 through 32767 include,
`unsigned int` is to  0 through 65535 include.

They are both coded on the same amount of bits, and thus, allocating X number of `int` and X number of `unsigned int` does not make a single difference.

As Mat pointed out, `calloc` doesn't even care what types you're giving it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your "always" in "should always make use of "unsigned" if there is no instance of a negative integer" is overly strong. It is largely a matter of personal preference and/or coding standard. There are arguments in favor of either approach. I personally prefer to follow that rule, i.e. all naturally unsigned quantities are represented by unsigned types in my code. But using a signed type in such cases does not necessarily represent a design error.

Secondly, all this has nothing to do with dynamic memory allocation or large arrays. How such arrays behave in memory is completely independent from what kind of data you store in them. Proper memory management is important for achieving good performance, but this is a completely independent matter, not in any way related to the question using signed or unsigned integer types.

Thirdly, even though unsigned types formally perform better in integer arithmetic, and even if your code performs massive amount of work with those integers, switching from signed to unsigned is unlikely to produce any notable improvement in performance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misinterpreting the advice you think you got. Whether to use signed or unsigned integer types can go either way with respect to performance, but unless you really need to optimize a particular bottleneck that you have **measured** to be a bottleneck, you should always be choosing the types that convey the intended semantic, not a type that "somebody told you is faster".

As for the specific question you asked, there is no way to search for data of a particular type "on the heap". Objects in C do not carry their types with them as part of their representation; while they formally *have* types, the type is represented in the code that accesses them, not in the objects themselves. So if you want to search for use of signed or unsigned integer objects, you should search your source code, not the heap. But again, this is not the way to solve a performance problem.

Answer (score 0):

Heap allocations is C are done with `malloc`, which knows nothing about your intent.